connecting java opentelemetry agent to jaeger using OTLP gives "unexpected end of stream"
There are many guides on configuring the opentelemetry java auto agent to use the Jaeger exporter contained in opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar
But jaeger exporter has been deprecated and removed, so the only way is now to use OTLP.  The question is how?
starting an example jaeger installation with the following:
docker run --name jaeger \
  -e COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true \
  -p 16686:16686 \
  -p 4317:4317 \
  -p 4318:4318 \
  jaegertracing/all-in-on

Some posts think that 4317 is the OTLP port so I'm going with this.
The java spring boot app is started like this:
java  -javaagent:myproj\src\main\resources\opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.javaagent.configuration-file=myproj\src\main\resources\otel-jaeger-config.properties -jar my.jar

The properties (java agent doesn't support yml) look like this:
otel.service.name=myservice
otel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://localhost:4317
otel.logs.exporter=none

otel.logs.exporter=none is needed to stop the java agent trying to send log files to Jaeger (Which cant handle them).
When the java app starts up, you get this error:
ERROR io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.http.HttpExporter - Failed to export spans. The request could not be executed. Full error message: unexpected end of stream on http://localhost:4317/...
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://localhost:4317/...

And in Jaeger docker, you see this output:
{"level":"info","ts":1727365210.185326,"caller":"transport/http2_server.go:298","msg":"[transport] [server-transport 0xc0004d4d00] Closing: connection error: desc = \"transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \\\"POST /v1/metrics HTTP/1.\\\"\""}
{"level":"info","ts":1727365210.1853955,"caller":"grpc@v1.66.2/server.go:994","msg":"[core] [Server #4]grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport: connection error: desc = \"transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \\\"POST /v1/metrics HTTP/1.\\\"\""}

I also tried the following config which I found for new relic:
otel.exporter.otlp.protocol=http/protobuf
otel.attribute.value.length.limit=4095
otel.experimental.resource.disabled-keys=process.command_args
otel.exporter.otlp.compression=gzip
otel.exporter.otlp.metrics.temporality.preference=delta

But the error does not change.

According to the logs the exporter is doing HTTP POST, so you need to point it to port 4318 (http), not 4317 (grpc).
